# Can I make home screen contact icons update their picture?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, contacts, home-screen, home-screen-shortcuts, contact-shortcut

I was just wondering if anyone knows how to make contact icons on the home screen update their picture when the contact's picture is changed, without needing to delete the shortcut and recreate it. Can this be done? Make the contact-shortcut's picture "live" as it were?

e.g. some of my contacts are linked to Facebook and their pictures on their contact records sync as expected, but the shortcut on the home screen will still show whatever their picture was when the shortcut was created.

I thought maybe rebooting the phone would cause it to refresh the icons, but it didn't.

Running on a non-rooted Galaxy S Captivate.

Comment: Good question.  The only way I've known how is removing and re-adding.  Hopefully there is a solution (might have to be a widget?)

Comment: Yes, I agree, good question.  I hope someone has an answer.  Like you guys, I have always had to delete and re-add.

Comment: Looks like it is logged as an Android [bug][1].  If I'm reading right, there is no current plan for the Android team to address this.


  [1]: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8697

Comment: @BCooksey Your comment should be the answer so @eidylon can mark it as answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like it is logged as an Android [bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8697). If I'm reading right, there is no current plan for the Android team to address this.